# SSL SNI missing when maven runs the code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, handshake, sni

I try to get an SSL secured site which requires SNI with asynchttpclient 2.0.24. Everything is fine in Eclipse. However when I run the code with maven I get handshake errors.

Allowing debug level ssl logging, it turned out that the server name is not registered during the maven build, the *"Extension server_name, server_name: ..."* line is missing from the log and it is present during Eclipse run. This is the only difference between the logs.
The weird thing is that in both cases the SslEngines's context contains the correct sniNames parameter.

Same JDK is used with Eclipse and Maven.

Any ideas what could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code that uses the default JDK connections has side effects which causes this weird behavior.

Comment: SNI was globally disabled in a static block of the legacy code...
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");